# How to extract search keywords from Google search result page URL by Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How do you extract search keywords from Google search result page URL by Swift?

I was simply trying to get stings after "&q=" but I found out I needed to consider more complicated cases such as "https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&q=test#q=speedtest+%E4%BE%A1%E6%A0%BC&hl=ja&prmd=nsiv&tbs=qdr:d"

I would appreciate your advice.

**Update:**
As per advised by LEO, I put this way.

```
if let url = NSURL(string: urlStr){

        var extractedQuery = ""
        if let fragment = url.fragment {
            extractedQuery = fragment
        } else if let query = url.query{
            extractedQuery = query
        }


        if let queryRange = extractedQuery.rangeOfString("&q="){
            let queryStartIndex = queryRange.endIndex
            let queryKeyword = extractedQuery.substringFromIndex(queryStartIndex)
            print(queryKeyword)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string to NSURL and access its query and fragment properties:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&q=test#q=speedtest+%E4%BE%A1%E6%A0%BC&hl=ja&prmd=nsiv&tbs=qdr:d"), query = url.query, fragment = url.fragment {
    print(query)    // "hl=ja&q=test\n"
    print(fragment) // "q=speedtest+%E4%BE%A1%E6%A0%BC&hl=ja&prmd=nsiv&tbs=qdr:d\n"
}
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know there were such parameters!

Comment: In the sample URL case, "=speedtest+%E4%BE%A1%E6%A0%BC" is the keyword I wanted to extract. ("test" was the original search query, and "=speedtest+%E4%BE%A1%E6%A0%BC" was the actual search query that was suggested by Google based on the original search and I selected it)

It looks like "fragment" parameter fetches the latter query keywords, so I made a logic so that if there is a fragment parameter, I use it, otherwise I use the original query keyword. 

I updated my question following the logic. What do you think?